# Creating a new section under css effects

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Hi guys so i am playing around with this tutorial right now [Link](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/01/02/fullscreen-background-image-slideshow-with-css3/)

And i created my backgrounds which work fine etc, now i want to add my new section right under that section but for some reason no section is appearing below it, its appearing above it, and i have no idea why :

HTML:

```
<ul class="cb-slideshow">
  <li><span>Image 01</span>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li><span>Image 02</span>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li><span>Image 03</span>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li><span>Image 04</span>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li><span>Image 05</span>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li><span>Image 06</span>
    <div></div>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="aboutus">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>ABOUT US</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.aboutus {
    height: 500px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Style Sheet From tutorial :

```
.cb-slideshow,
.cb-slideshow:after {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 0;
}
.cb-slideshow:after {
    content: '';
    background: transparent url(../images/pattern.png) repeat top left;
}
.cb-slideshow li span {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: none;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
}
.cb-slideshow li div {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
}
.cb-slideshow li div h3 {
    font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 160px;
    padding: 0 30px;
    line-height: 120px;
    color: rgba(169,3,41, 0.8);
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(1) span { background-image: url(../images/6.jpg) }
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) span {
    background-image: url(../images/5.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
    -o-animation-delay: 6s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-delay: 6s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) span {
    background-image: url(../images/4.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
    -o-animation-delay: 12s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
    animation-delay: 12s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4) span {
    background-image: url(../images/3.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
    -o-animation-delay: 18s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
    animation-delay: 18s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(5) span {
    background-image: url(../images/2.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
    -o-animation-delay: 24s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
    animation-delay: 24s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(6) span {
    background-image: url(../images/1.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 30s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 30s;
    -o-animation-delay: 30s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 30s;
    animation-delay: 30s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
    -o-animation-delay: 6s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-delay: 6s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
    -o-animation-delay: 12s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
    animation-delay: 12s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
    -o-animation-delay: 18s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
    animation-delay: 18s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(5) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
    -o-animation-delay: 24s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
    animation-delay: 24s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(6) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 30s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 30s;
    -o-animation-delay: 30s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 30s;
    animation-delay: 30s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
    }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-moz-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: scale(1.05);
        -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
    }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-o-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -o-transform: scale(1.05);
        -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -o-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
        -o-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
    }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-ms-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-transform: scale(1.05);
        -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
        -ms-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
    }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1.05);
        animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
    }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-webkit-keyframes titleAnimation { 
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(200px);
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    19% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-400px);
    }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-moz-keyframes titleAnimation { 
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: translateX(200px);
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    19% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: translateX(-400px);
    }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-o-keyframes titleAnimation { 
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -o-transform: translateX(200px);
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -o-transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -o-transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    19% {
        opacity: 0;
        -o-transform: translateX(-400px);
    }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-ms-keyframes titleAnimation { 
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -ms-transform: translateX(200px);
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    19% {
        opacity: 0;
        -ms-transform: translateX(-400px);
    }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@keyframes titleAnimation { 
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(200px);
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    19% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(-400px);
    }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
/* Show at least something when animations not supported */
.no-cssanimations .cb-slideshow li span{
    opacity: 1;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1140px) { 
    .cb-slideshow li div h3 { font-size: 100px }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) { 
    .cb-slideshow li div h3 { font-size: 50px }
}
```

So everything is working perfectly right now, i got the backtround images to load and the animations look beautiful etc, but i want to start my new section about us right under slideshow but for some reason its appearing ontop of it and its dispersing all the time is well and i have no clue why. I am also using bootstrap 3 with this demo page

Thanks

Comment: what are you use framework for this? if you are used bootstrap you can  make `container`

Comment: @core114 i tried didn't work, i used one of the answers below but it didn't work fully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `display: fixed;` from `.cb-slideshow` class. Because fixed section always viewed on top and other elements start above or below this section.

Here is the css properties which I changed in `.cb-slideshow` class:

```
.cb-slideshow,
.cb-slideshow:after { 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 0; 
    height: 662px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
```

```css
body, ul { 
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
html,body {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
ul {
 list-style:none;
}
body{
 background: #000;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 15px;
 color: #aa3e03;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}
h1 {
    margin: 0
}
.container{
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
}
.aboutus {
    height: 500px;
    background-color: blue;
    padding-top: 20px;
    color: #fff;
}
.cb-slideshow,
.cb-slideshow:after { 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 0; 
    height: 662px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.cb-slideshow:after { 
    content: '';
    background: transparent url(../images/pattern.png) repeat top left; 
}
.cb-slideshow li span { 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: none;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li div { 
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li div h3 { 
    font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 240px;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 200px; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(1) span { 
    background-image: url('https://image.ibb.co/bFH276/1.jpg') 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) span { 
    background-image: url('https://image.ibb.co/kHoELR/2.jpg');
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
    -o-animation-delay: 6s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-delay: 6s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) span { 
    background-image: url('https://image.ibb.co/g7xVum/3.jpg');
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
    -o-animation-delay: 12s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
    animation-delay: 12s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4) span { 
    background-image: url('https://image.ibb.co/d81OEm/4.jpg');
    -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
    -o-animation-delay: 18s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
    animation-delay: 18s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(5) span { 
    background-image: url('https://image.ibb.co/ejben6/5.jpg');
    -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
    -o-animation-delay: 24s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
    animation-delay: 24s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(6) span { 
    background-image: url('https://image.ibb.co/gahKn6/6.jpg');
    -webkit-animation-delay: 30s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 30s;
    -o-animation-delay: 30s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 30s;
    animation-delay: 30s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) div { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
    -o-animation-delay: 6s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-delay: 6s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) div { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
    -o-animation-delay: 12s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
    animation-delay: 12s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4) div { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
    -o-animation-delay: 18s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
    animation-delay: 18s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(5) div { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
    -o-animation-delay: 24s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
    animation-delay: 24s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(6) div { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 30s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 30s;
    -o-animation-delay: 30s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 30s;
    animation-delay: 30s; 
}
/* Animation for the slideshow images */
@-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-moz-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-o-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-ms-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
/* Animation for the title */
@-webkit-keyframes titleAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0 }
    8% { opacity: 1 }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    19% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-moz-keyframes titleAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0 }
    8% { opacity: 1 }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    19% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-o-keyframes titleAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0 }
    8% { opacity: 1 }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    19% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-ms-keyframes titleAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0 }
    8% { opacity: 1 }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    19% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@keyframes titleAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0 }
    8% { opacity: 1 }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    19% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
/* Show at least something when animations not supported */
.no-cssanimations .cb-slideshow li span{
 opacity: 1;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1140px) { 
    .cb-slideshow li div h3 { font-size: 140px }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) { 
    .cb-slideshow li div h3 { font-size: 80px }
}
```

```html
    <body id="page">
        <ul class="cb-slideshow">
            <li><span>Image 01</span><div><h3>re·lax·a·tion</h3></div></li>
            <li><span>Image 02</span><div><h3>qui·e·tude</h3></div></li>
            <li><span>Image 03</span><div><h3>bal·ance</h3></div></li>
            <li><span>Image 04</span><div><h3>e·qua·nim·i·ty</h3></div></li>
            <li><span>Image 05</span><div><h3>com·po·sure</h3></div></li>
            <li><span>Image 06</span><div><h3>se·ren·i·ty</h3></div></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="aboutus">
            <div class="container">
                <h1> ABOUT US </h1>
            </div>
        </div>        
    </body>
```

**UPDATE**

I changed in `.cb-slideshow` class

```
.cb-slideshow,
.cb-slideshow:after{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 0; 
    height: 662px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```css
body, ul { 
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
html,body {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
ul {
 list-style:none;
}
body{
 background: #000;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 15px;
 color: #aa3e03;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}
h1 {
    margin: 0
}
.container{
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
}
.aboutus {
    height: 500px;
    background-color: blue;
    padding-top: 20px;
    color: #fff;
}
.cb-slideshow,
.cb-slideshow:after {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 0; 
    height: 662px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.cb-slideshow:after {
    content: '';
    background: transparent url('https://image.ibb.co/d4Ls76/pattern.png') repeat top left;
}
.cb-slideshow li span {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: none;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
}
.cb-slideshow li div {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
}
.cb-slideshow li div h3 {
    font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 160px;
    padding: 0 30px;
    line-height: 120px;
    color: rgba(169,3,41, 0.8);
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(1) span { 
background-image: url('https://image.ibb.co/gahKn6/6.jpg') 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) span {
    background-image: url('https://image.ibb.co/ejben6/5.jpg');
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
    -o-animation-delay: 6s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-delay: 6s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) span {
    background-image: url('https://image.ibb.co/d81OEm/4.jpg');
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
    -o-animation-delay: 12s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
    animation-delay: 12s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4) span {
    background-image: url('https://image.ibb.co/g7xVum/3.jpg');
    -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
    -o-animation-delay: 18s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
    animation-delay: 18s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(5) span {
    background-image: url('https://image.ibb.co/kHoELR/2.jpg');
    -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
    -o-animation-delay: 24s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
    animation-delay: 24s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(6) span {
    background-image: url('https://image.ibb.co/bFH276/1.jpg');
    -webkit-animation-delay: 30s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 30s;
    -o-animation-delay: 30s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 30s;
    animation-delay: 30s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
    -o-animation-delay: 6s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-delay: 6s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
    -o-animation-delay: 12s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
    animation-delay: 12s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
    -o-animation-delay: 18s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
    animation-delay: 18s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(5) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
    -o-animation-delay: 24s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
    animation-delay: 24s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(6) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 30s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 30s;
    -o-animation-delay: 30s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 30s;
    animation-delay: 30s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation { 
 0% {
     opacity: 0;
     -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
 }
 8% {
     opacity: 1;
     -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
     -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
 }
 17% {
     opacity: 1;
     -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
 }
 25% {
     opacity: 0;
     -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
 }
 100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-moz-keyframes imageAnimation { 
 0% {
     opacity: 0;
     -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
 }
 8% {
     opacity: 1;
     -moz-transform: scale(1.05);
     -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
 }
 17% {
     opacity: 1;
     -moz-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
 }
 25% {
     opacity: 0;
     -moz-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
 }
 100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-o-keyframes imageAnimation { 
 0% {
     opacity: 0;
     -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
 }
 8% {
     opacity: 1;
     -o-transform: scale(1.05);
     -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
 }
 17% {
     opacity: 1;
     -o-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
 }
 25% {
     opacity: 0;
     -o-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
 }
 100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-ms-keyframes imageAnimation { 
 0% {
     opacity: 0;
     -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
 }
 8% {
     opacity: 1;
     -ms-transform: scale(1.05);
     -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
 }
 17% {
     opacity: 1;
     -ms-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
 }
 25% {
     opacity: 0;
     -ms-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
 }
 100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@keyframes imageAnimation { 
 0% {
     opacity: 0;
     animation-timing-function: ease-in;
 }
 8% {
     opacity: 1;
     transform: scale(1.05);
     animation-timing-function: ease-out;
 }
 17% {
     opacity: 1;
     transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
 }
 25% {
     opacity: 0;
     transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
 }
 100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-webkit-keyframes titleAnimation { 
 0% {
     opacity: 0;
     -webkit-transform: translateX(200px);
 }
 8% {
     opacity: 1;
     -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
 }
 17% {
     opacity: 1;
     -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
 }
 19% {
     opacity: 0;
     -webkit-transform: translateX(-400px);
 }
 25% { opacity: 0 }
 100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-moz-keyframes titleAnimation { 
 0% {
     opacity: 0;
     -moz-transform: translateX(200px);
 }
 8% {
     opacity: 1;
     -moz-transform: translateX(0px);
 }
 17% {
     opacity: 1;
     -moz-transform: translateX(0px);
 }
 19% {
     opacity: 0;
     -moz-transform: translateX(-400px);
 }
 25% { opacity: 0 }
 100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-o-keyframes titleAnimation { 
 0% {
     opacity: 0;
     -o-transform: translateX(200px);
 }
 8% {
     opacity: 1;
     -o-transform: translateX(0px);
 }
 17% {
     opacity: 1;
     -o-transform: translateX(0px);
 }
 19% {
     opacity: 0;
     -o-transform: translateX(-400px);
 }
 25% { opacity: 0 }
 100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-ms-keyframes titleAnimation { 
 0% {
     opacity: 0;
     -ms-transform: translateX(200px);
 }
 8% {
     opacity: 1;
     -ms-transform: translateX(0px);
 }
 17% {
     opacity: 1;
     -ms-transform: translateX(0px);
 }
 19% {
     opacity: 0;
     -ms-transform: translateX(-400px);
 }
 25% { opacity: 0 }
 100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@keyframes titleAnimation { 
 0% {
     opacity: 0;
     transform: translateX(200px);
 }
 8% {
     opacity: 1;
     transform: translateX(0px);
 }
 17% {
     opacity: 1;
     transform: translateX(0px);
 }
 19% {
     opacity: 0;
     transform: translateX(-400px);
 }
 25% { opacity: 0 }
 100% { opacity: 0 }
}
/* Show at least something when animations not supported */
.no-cssanimations .cb-slideshow li span{
 opacity: 1;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1140px) { 
 .cb-slideshow li div h3 { font-size: 100px }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) { 
 .cb-slideshow li div h3 { font-size: 50px }
}
```

```html
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style2.css" />
        <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.0.6/modernizr.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    </head>
    <body id="page">
        <ul class="cb-slideshow">
            <li><span>Image 01</span><div><h3>se·ren·i·ty</h3></div></li>
            <li><span>Image 02</span><div><h3>com·po·sure</h3></div></li>
            <li><span>Image 03</span><div><h3>e·qua·nim·i·ty</h3></div></li>
            <li><span>Image 04</span><div><h3>bal·ance</h3></div></li>
            <li><span>Image 05</span><div><h3>qui·e·tude</h3></div></li>
            <li><span>Image 06</span><div><h3>re·lax·a·tion</h3></div></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="aboutus">
            <div class="container">
                <h1> ABOUT US </h1>
            </div>
        </div>   
    </body>
```

Comment: Thanks perfect :)

Comment: You're welcome! :) Good luck! Which effect, fade in/out?

Comment: the effect of the zoom in function and out, the keyframes

Comment: It looks perfect now, the images are on the top , the section is alone , but the keyframes animations on the images stopped working

Comment: Ok. I understood. No problem I can fix it.

Comment: Thanks :) for all the help

Comment: Which demo you wanted?

Comment: Demo 2 is the one

Comment: Ok. I looked Demo 1. Ok wait a few minutes ;)

Comment: Ah no problem at all :) look forward to seeing it , thanks again

Comment: Check it please :)

Comment: Amazing work thank you so much , had no idea it was going to be this difficult :) but thanks again  , i also used height:100vh; just so it can stretch to whole screen size :)

Comment: Thank you too. :) I am glad it helped. I said it was interesting for me. Take care. Good luck Ron! ;)

Answer (score 0):

This might resolve the issue:

```
.aboutus {
clear:both;
display:block
}
```

Comment: gave some possible reasons. Was it one of those reasons? Or something else? It might be useful for future readers to understand what the underlying issue was.